# Rails form_tag not POSTing, GETing on the source page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It's been a while since I've needed anything but a `form_for`.

Now I'm trying to set up an admin area search where the search box is in the menu bar. But instead of POSTing to the results path it's reloading the existing page with GET params, including the `authenticity_token`.

So my set up:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# And so on....
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :results do #search results
        collection do
            get :display
        end
    end

    # many more routes here
end
```

**admin/results_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::ResultsController < ApplicationController

    def display
        @results = Elasticsearch::Model.search(params[:query], [Article]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
        end
    end

    private 

        # Don't think this is really relevant, adding out of desparation
        def result_params
            params.require(:result).permit(:query)
        end
end
```

And in my universal admin bar:

```
<%= form_tag(display_admin_results_path, method: :post) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], {class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search"} %>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><%= submit_tag "&rarr;".html_safe, class: "btn btn-success" %></span>
 <% end %>
```

Logs show no sign of a redirection, Chome console shows no javascript "bork."

Instead of submitting that form and getting sent to `/admin/results/display` or even `/admin/results/display?query=blah` I'm gettting

```
?utf8=✓&authenticity_token=j3w4dtBbFLzJzqWGZ9x4Q4GsUi%2FxmjYFrPjdzm8ccLKdxpOR0KwrX2hIAzXkR96cuTVgwG1sbYBKDdSO%2F3O6Wg%3D%3D&query=hello&commit=→
```

It's got to be something obvious... prepared for the 'doh' moment.

Comment: that is the issue with not used by you ajax call

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your routes. 
In your console write `rails routes` (or `rake routes`), and you will see that it expects get method for your `display_admin_results_path`. So you access your controller with GET method.

your routes:

```
display_admin_results GET    /admin/results/display(.:format) admin/results#display
        admin_results GET    /admin/results(.:format)         admin/results#index
                      POST   /admin/results(.:format)         admin/results#create
         admin_result GET    /admin/results/:id(.:format)     admin/results#show
                      PATCH  /admin/results/:id(.:format)     admin/results#update
                      PUT    /admin/results/:id(.:format)     admin/results#update
                      DELETE /admin/results/:id(.:format)     admin/results#destroy
```

You should implement your search query, so that it will use POST, and return corresponding view(which is defenetly not index).

Also, you render method searches the view with coresponding name, so you may want to create `display.html.erb file`, or specify the view you want to use in controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've since changed the route to ``post :display`` and I've got ``POST   /admin/results/display(.:format)`` when I run ``rake routes``. I'm wondering if it is something to do with AJAX as per @TusharPal but I have to say I'm not sure where to start with that suggestion.

Comment: did you write separate  view for this action? @Paulus

Comment: Yep: ``views/admin/results/display.html.erb``